# Postgresql: find all the allowed values for a domain

Tags: postgresql, verification

Suppose I created the following domain:

```
CREATE DOMAIN MY_STATUS AS VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT 'STATUS0' CHECK(VALUE in ('STATUS1', 'STATUS2', 'STATUS3'));
```

As expected, in a column whose type is MY_STATUS, i can put only the values:

- 'STATUS0'
- 'STATUS1'
- 'STATUS2'
- 'STATUS3'

Now, let's suppose that I want to validate this column before to send an insert or update to my DB. I need to know which values are allowed so that, if I have status = STATUS4, I will have an error before to send the insert to DB and I can manage it. Since the domain may change in the future, I need to select all the allowed values from DB rather than hardcode all possible values creating constants.

Shortly: how to make a query that selects all the possible values of the domain?
In my example, I would like to have a query that will return:

```
'STATUS0', 'STATUS1', 'STATUS2', 'STATUS3'
```

Comment: `'STATUS0'` is not a valid value in your table, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/PWRKKeqt

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a foreign key reference rather than a type or `check` constraint.  Although you can devise a complex query to parse the the constraint, this is so much easier with a foreign key:

```
create table valid_domain_statuses (
    status varchar(32) primary key
);

insert into valid_domain_statuses (status)
    select 'STATUS0' union all
    select 'STATUS1' union all
    select 'STATUS2' union all
    select 'STATUS3' ;

. . .

alter table t add constraint fk_my_status
    foreign key (status) references valid_domain_statuses(status);
```

This has other advantages:

- You can readily see the valid values by looking at the table.
- You can add additional information about the statuses.
- It is easy to add new status values.

Comment: OK, but do you know if that query is possible? Because i found already the DB in that way.

Comment: I mean, i didn't decide the structure of the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the list of check constraint values of a domain is possible. You need to inspect the textual declaration of the domain with a regular expression, searching for the 'value' pattern. The following is a function of mine that lists all the allowed values as a JSON array.

```sql
--
-- function:  jget_domain_values
-- purpose:   Produce a JSON array with all the check constraint values of a domain type
-- returns:   A JSON array.
-- since:     1.2.20
--
create or replace function jget_domain_values (
  _domain_name varchar
)
returns json
stable language sql as $$
  select 
    -- aggregate a JSON array after removing the first and last character
    -- of the captured values, which include apostrophes
    json_agg(substring(tj.l from 2 for char_length(tj.l)-2))
  from (
    -- capture the check constraint values of tlang from pg_constraint table
    select  (regexp_matches(pg_get_constraintdef(tc.oid), '''\w+''', 'g'))[1] as l
    from    pg_namespace tn
    join    pg_constraint tc on tn.oid = tc.connamespace
    join    pg_type tt on tt.oid = tc.contypid
    where   tn.nspname = current_schema()
    and     tt.typname = _domain_name
  ) tj;
$$;
```

and this is an alternative function, returning a set of varchars

```sql
--
-- function:  get_domain_values
-- purpose:   Produce a JSON array with all the check constraint values of a domain type
-- returns:   a set of values
-- since:     1.2.20
--
create or replace function get_domain_values (
  _domain_name varchar
)
returns setof varchar
stable language sql as $$
  -- remove the apostrophes at the first and last characters of the captured values
  select 
    substring(t.l from 2 for char_length(t.l)-2)
  from (
    -- capture the check constraint values of tlang from pg_constraint table
    select  (regexp_matches(pg_get_constraintdef(tc.oid), '''\w+''', 'g'))[1] as l
    from    pg_namespace tn
    join    pg_constraint tc on tn.oid = tc.connamespace
    join    pg_type tt on tt.oid = tc.contypid
    where   tn.nspname = current_schema()
    and     tt.typname = _domain_name
  ) t;
$$;
```